# Save XML to MSSQL

Tags: xml, t-sql, xquery, sql-server-2019

I am trying to save this XML into a MSSQL database (XML is below).

I have been using this code as a starting point:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5707/simple-way-to-import-xml-data-into-sql-server-with-tsql/

Everything works well (yeah!), except the last field "Transaction_ID" (bummer...).
The 4 values of the last field are placed after each other in the SQL table. And I would like to have the values in separate records.

This is part of the code I used to convert the last field into MSSQL:

```
MY_XML.XML1.query('Transactions/Transaction_ID').value('.','VARCHAR(255)')



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
<Session>
<Record_ID>000029837OYMV22fdewSY12IuRBUlxqq=</Record_ID>
<Extraction_Date>2020-03-25T14:02:29</Extraction_Date>
<Company_ID>Company1</Company_ID>
<ID>Product2</ID>
<Session_ID>000029837OYMV22fdewSY12IuRBUlxqq=</Session_ID>
<Session_Start_Datetime>2019-11-21T15:21:59</Session_Start_Datetime>
<Session_End_Datetime>2020-05-11T15:26:36</Session_End_Datetime>
<Session_Commission>25</Session_Commission>
<Transactions>
<Transaction_ID>1</Transaction_ID>
<Transaction_ID>2</Transaction_ID>
<Transaction_ID>3</Transaction_ID>
<Transaction_ID>4</Transaction_ID>
</Transactions>
</Session>
</Root>
```

1. is our data model the issue?
2. is the XML we received the issue?
3. is my code the issue?
4. or do I need to save the transaction_IDs and a key in a separate SQL table?

Thanks!

All the best,
Sharon

Comment: Your code is the issue. The code snippet looks to be from the SELECT column list so it's returning all the text of the matching nodes. You need to specify it in a `FROM` clause (maybe using the `nodes` method) in order to return multiple `Transaction_ID` elements before extracting the element text using the `value` method. Add the full query to your question if you need help with that.

Comment: Sharon, While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL for your target table(s), i.e. T-SQL CREATE table(s). 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your T-SQL code attempt implementation of it. 
(3) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
declare @doc xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
<Session>
<Record_ID>000029837OYMV22fdewSY12IuRBUlxqq=</Record_ID>
<Extraction_Date>2020-03-25T14:02:29</Extraction_Date>
<Company_ID>Company1</Company_ID>
<ID>Product2</ID>
<Session_ID>000029837OYMV22fdewSY12IuRBUlxqq=</Session_ID>
<Session_Start_Datetime>2019-11-21T15:21:59</Session_Start_Datetime>
<Session_End_Datetime>2020-05-11T15:26:36</Session_End_Datetime>
<Session_Commission>25</Session_Commission>
<Transactions>
<Transaction_ID>1</Transaction_ID>
<Transaction_ID>2</Transaction_ID>
<Transaction_ID>3</Transaction_ID>
<Transaction_ID>4</Transaction_ID>
</Transactions>
</Session>
</Root>'

select 
    session.value('(Record_ID)[1]', 'varchar(40)') Record_ID,
    session.value('(Session_End_Datetime)[1]', 'datetime') Session_End_Datetime,
    tranid.value('.', 'int') Transaction_ID
from @doc.nodes('/Root/Session') doc(session)
cross apply session.nodes('Transactions/Transaction_ID') transactions(tranid)
```

which outputs

```
Record_ID                                Session_End_Datetime    Transaction_ID
---------------------------------------- ----------------------- --------------
000029837OYMV22fdewSY12IuRBUlxqq=        2020-05-11 15:26:36.000 1
000029837OYMV22fdewSY12IuRBUlxqq=        2020-05-11 15:26:36.000 2
000029837OYMV22fdewSY12IuRBUlxqq=        2020-05-11 15:26:36.000 3
000029837OYMV22fdewSY12IuRBUlxqq=        2020-05-11 15:26:36.000 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following to convert **ANY XML** file to a SQL Table. It uses the xml format to determine if it is a new record or not.  It also separate attributes as a new record but flag them.  You can easily reconstructed back the xml

USE:

```
select *  from Utility.FlattenXml('your xml’)
```

PROCEDURE:

```
USE [YOUR_DB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [Utility].[FlattenXml](@xmlDoc XML)  
RETURNS TABLE 
AS RETURN 
WITH CTE AS ( 

    SELECT 
            1 AS lvl,  
            x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Name,  
            CAST(NULL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS ParentName, 
            CAST(1 AS INT) AS ParentPosition, 
            CAST(N'Element' AS NVARCHAR(20)) AS NodeType,  
            x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS FullPath,  
            x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)')  
            + N'[' 
            + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS NVARCHAR)  
            + N']' AS XPath,  
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Position, 
            x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Tree,  
            x.value('text()[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Value,  
            x.query('.') AS this,         
            x.query('*') AS t,  
            CAST(CAST(1 AS VARBINARY(4)) AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS Sort,  
            CAST(1 AS INT) AS ID  
    FROM @xmlDoc.nodes('/*') a(x)  
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
            p.lvl + 1 AS lvl,  
            c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Name,  
            CAST(p.Name AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS ParentName, 
            CAST(p.Position AS INT) AS ParentPosition, 
            CAST(N'Element' AS NVARCHAR(20)) AS NodeType,  
            CAST(p.FullPath + N'/' + c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS FullPath,  
            CAST(p.XPath + N'/'+ c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)')+ N'['+ CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
            ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS NVARCHAR)+ N']' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS XPath,  
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
            ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Position, 
            CAST( SPACE(2 * p.lvl - 1) + N'|' + REPLICATE(N'-', 1) + c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS Tree,  
            CAST( c.value('text()[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) AS Value, c.query('.') AS this,  
            c.query('*') AS t,  
            CAST(p.Sort + CAST( (lvl + 1) * 1024 + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) * 2) AS VARBINARY(4)) AS VARBINARY(MAX) ) AS Sort,  
            CAST((lvl + 1) * 1024 + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) * 2) AS INT)
            
    FROM CTE p  
    CROSS APPLY p.t.nodes('*') b(c)), cte2 AS (  
                                                SELECT 
                                                lvl AS Depth,  
                                                Name AS NodeName,  
                                                ParentName, 
                                                ParentPosition, 
                                                NodeType,  
                                                FullPath,  
                                                XPath,  
                                                Position, 
                                                Tree AS TreeView,  
                                                Value,  
                                                this AS XMLData,  
                                                Sort, 
                                                ID
                                                FROM cte  
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
            p.lvl,  
            x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
            p.Name, 
            p.Position, 
            CAST(N'Attribute' AS NVARCHAR(20)),  
            p.FullPath + N'/@' + x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
            p.XPath + N'/@' + x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
            1, 
            SPACE(2 * p.lvl - 1) + N'|' + REPLICATE('-', 1)  
            + N'@' + x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
            x.value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
            NULL,  
            p.Sort,  
            p.ID + 1  
    FROM CTE p  
    CROSS APPLY this.nodes('/*/@*') a(x)  
    )  

    SELECT into [your table]
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Sort, ID) AS ID,  
            ParentName, ParentPosition,Depth, NodeName, Position,   
            NodeType, FullPath, XPath, TreeView, Value, XMLData 
    FROM CTE2
```